# CustomControl, objects don't exist in namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Confused as to what is going wrong here, i'm getting an error saying `local:NumericValue does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Controls` on the following

```
   <local:NumericValue x:Key="NumericValue" />
```

And getting `The member "Template" is not recognized or is not accessible` on this line:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
```

I can't figure out why, I have attempted to add `Assembly=Controls` to the end of the `local` property in the ResourceDictionary tag, and I have clicked `Clean Solution` and `Rebuild Solution` multiple times in case it's a build error but still getting the same issue!

Here is the code;
**XAML - Themes/Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Controls">
    <local:NumericValue x:Key="NumericValue" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NumericUpDown}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:NumericUpDown}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Button Grid.Column="0">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Path Data="M0,0 L1,0 0.5,1Z" 
                                      Width="20" 
                                      Height="20" 
                                      Fill="White"
                                      Stretch="Fill"/>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>

                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource NumericUpDown},Path=value}" />

                        <Button Grid.Column="2">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Path Data="M0,1 L1,1 0.5,0Z" 
                                      Width="20" 
                                      Height="20" 
                                      Fill="White" 
                                      Stretch="Fill" />
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Code Behind - NumericUpDown**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Controls
{
    public class NumericUpDown : FrameworkElement
    {
        static NumericUpDown()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NumericUpDown), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NumericUpDown)));
        }
    }
    public class NumericValue
    {
        private int _value;
        public int value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why `NumericValue` isn't recognized, but regarding the other error:

> The member "Template" is not recognized or is not accessible

This is because your custom control inherits from `FrameworkElement`, but the `Template` is defined in the `Control` class. Just change your NumericUpDown class so that it inherits from `Control` instead.

Comment: Ah I was under the impression that `FrameworkElement` gives the control more freedom with things such as Data Binding which the `Control` class doesn't?

Comment: @MartynBall, Control inherits from FrameworkElement, so it can do anything FrameworkElement can do ;)